# Probability paradox: Mario's dice game

Tags: probability

Consider the following:

Mario invites an infinite number of friends to a party, and challenges them at a game.

First, Mario randomly splits his infinite friends in groups of incremental size, the first group having 1 person, the second group having 9, the third having 90 an so on

More generally, being $s$ the size in people of the $x$th group (starting from 0):
$$s(0)=1$$
$$s(x)=9・10^x\tag{x>0}$$

Mario then challenges one group after another in order, from group 0 on, until he wins.

Mario always loses to the first group(with one person only).
From the second group on, the challenge consists in throwing a 10-face dice, if 10 is the result Mario wins, otherwise everyone belonging to the challenging group wins (but the game goes on).

If Mario loses, he goes on challenging the next group, until he wins.
In the exact moment Mario wins, the game ends.

When the game ends, there will be a number of winners and a number of losers, the losers being the people of the group that had the last challenge with Mario and lost to him.
Mario always wins in the end.

The question is: Being me one of Mario's friends, what is the probability of me winning supposing that I participated?

I could come up with 2 different logic that show an opposite result, and would like to know which one of them is wrong and where exactly.

**Definitions**

$p_{game}=9/10$ is the probability of winning a single direct game against Mario
$w$ Is the event of me winning
$p$ Is the event of me participating to the game (being selected by Mario at some time)
$p(w|p)$ is the probability of me winning ($w$) supposing that I participate ($p$)

**Problem**: Find $p(w|p)$

**Logic 1**

$p \implies$ A single game between my group and Mario will take place
$\implies$ $p(w|p)=p_{game} = 9/10$

So I have a 9/10 probability of winning supposing I take part in the game.

**Logic 2**

Suppose the game ended at turn $t$, consider the total number of winners and losers excluding Mario at the end of the game:

The number of losers is just the size of the only group that lost to Mario, that is
$$losers=s(t)=9・10^t$$

The number of winners is the sum of number of people of all groups up to and excluding the losers group:
$$winners=\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}s(i)=\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}9・10^i+1$$
$p\implies$ I belong either to the winners or the losers.
The probability of me being a $winner$ is therefore: 
$$p(w|p)=winners/(winners+losers)$$
$$\implies p(w|p)=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}9・10^i+1}{9・10^t+\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}9・10^i+1}$$
$$\implies p(w|p)=\frac{9・10^{t-1}+9・10^{t-2}+...+9+1}{9・10^t+9・10^{t-1}+9・10^{t-2}+...+9+1}$$
$$\implies p(w|p)=\frac{9・10^{t-1}+9・10^{t-2}+...+9+1}{10(9・10^{t-1}+9・10^{t-2}+9・10^{t-3}+...+9+1}$$
$$\implies p(w|p)=\frac{1}{10}$$

Which logic is wrong and where?
Is there any specific theory that I'm missing here?

Comment: since you did not specify how Mario splits his infinitely many guests into groups, you can't possible determine the probability of you belonging to a specific group and thus you can't perform any computation.

Comment: Is it fair to say that he splits the groups randomly?  Let's say he picks one person at random, then 9, then 90, then 900 and so on, so that the groups are split, with uniform probability over all friends.

Comment: There is no such thing as "pick randomly". You have to specify the probability distribution. Usually, when saying "pick randomly" one means "pick using the uniform distribution". However, there is no such thing as a uniform distribution on an infinite discrete set, which is often the cause to many 'paradoxes'.

Comment: I thought that you can have an uniform distribution over an infinite discrete set, that is p(x) = 0 for every x, which, if I understood it correctly, does not imply that no number can be picked... (p=0 does not mean "impossible event", right?)

Comment: Try to describe a uniform distribution on $\mathbb N$. Saying $p(x)=0$ for every $x\in \mathbb N$ does not describe a probability distribution since the probabilities have to add-up to $1$.

Comment: I see... that sounds like a reasonable argument.  So it is not allowed to think about a uniform random pick over a discrete finite set, because the distribution cannot be defined without generating an absurd I guess?

Comment: assuming you meant "over a discrete infinite set" then yes, that is very correct.

Comment: The number of people in the group don't matter.  You just asked what is the chance that you win, assuming you play.  The fact that you have more people in your group, who will win or lose wih you is not important.  Your Logic 1 is just fine.

Comment: I still don't see the flaw in logic 2, you have to be one of the people that are participating after all.
Ittay Weiss -> If you turn that in an answer I think I'm going to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason **Logic 2** doesn't work is that the proviso that you **will** play the game has changed the rules.

If you are in group $i$, then everyone id groups $0$ to $i-1$ is *guaranteed* to lose, otherwise you would not be playing. So these groups don't count.

Similarly, for groups $i+1$ on to exist, you must have lost.

Comment: If I understood correctly, your point is then that the probability of "being" any of the people who participated in the game is not uniform?

Comment: Not only not uniform, not defined.

Comment: So we are forbid to talk about the "probability of winning knowing that you participated"?

Comment: Far be it for me to forbid anything. However, by specifying that you participated, you change the basis of the sample space and your 2nd logic is therefore invalid.

Comment: I see, what exact step of logic 2 you consider to be floppy? There should be an implication that is not true in that case^^

Answer (score 1):

On a purely theoretical level Mario is actually extracting a natural number from an infinite sample if you consider the rules he is following.

for example if he throws 6 8 3 4 9 10(end) then he extracted the number: 94386

However he is doing that with restrictions.
The first restriction is that he can never extract a number that has "0" in it. The second, and more important restriction, is that the higher is the magnitude of a number the lower is the probability for it to be extracted. Any number in a given order of magnitude has 90% more probability to be extracted than the numbers in the order of magnitude directly above.
Because of that, on a practical level, he will "almost certainly" extract a number from a reasonably finite sample.

On the other side there is another extraction that is of the player that must participate in the game. If you suppose that he extracts a number to decide which turn he will play in, then the rules that he must follow are exactly reversed: any number must have 90% more probability to be extracted than the number directly below.
This makes it an impossible extraction on all practical levels, and probably logical too.

Comment: I perfectly understand your case 1: the sequence that Mario throws represent a natural number extracted from an infinite discrete set with non-uniform probability (and thus it is possible), but why for partecipating you have increasing probability? I thought it should be 0 for all natural numbers.